# Does Ant Design date picker allow you to pick a date by typing the date into the input box?

Tags: antd

Based on https://ant.design/components/date-picker/,
Date picker allows you to enter a date into the input field but it wont be accepted by the date picker.

Can anyone confirm if this is true?

Comment: You have to use the configured date format in order to enter the date in plain text form. Default is `YYYY-MM-DD`